# How to Mix 2 arrays in ratio 1to3?

Tags: php

There was a task to mix two arrays in the ratio "1to3"
Those. 2 arrays.

1st array

> 100,200,300,400,500

2nd array

> 111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120

Must exit in a new array

> 100,111,112,113,200,114,115,116,300,117,118,119,400,120

I just can not think ... maybe some function

I have

```
$pervo=Array();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM  `zayvki` WHERE `prioretet`='2' AND `status`='1' AND `let`='2' ORDER BY `dataZayvki` ASC";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($itog = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    $pervo[]=$itog['id'];
}
```

AND

```
$obych=Array();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM  `zayvki` WHERE `prioretet`='0' AND `status`='1' AND `let`='2' ORDER BY `dataZayvki` ASC";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($itog = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    $obych[]=$itog['id'];
}
```

But I'm not sure thath it's correct

Comment: Why not use just 1 query: `SELECT * FROM  'zayvki' WHERE 'prioretet' IN ('2','0') [...]`?

Comment: [array_chunk](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) might be of use

Answer (score 0):

loop first array and used `array_slice()` to get 3 values from second array then merge value from first array and 3 values from second array.

```
$arr1 = array(100,200,300,400,500);
$arr2 = array(111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120);
$start = 0;
$len = count($arr2);
$newArr = array();
foreach($arr1 as $val){
    if($start <= $len){
        //$newArr[] = $val;
        $temp = array_merge([$val],array_slice($arr2, $start, 3)) ;
        $newArr = array_merge($newArr, $temp);
    }
    $start +=3;
}
print_r($newArr);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/BsPRM)

Comment: It's not correct
$arr1 = array(100,200,300,400,500,600,700);
$arr2 = array(111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120);

Where elements from arr1 600,700?